# How to place a scroll down arrow at the bottom of a button card

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

My card component renders a button and looks something like this

```
  const SearchCard = () => (
    <div>
      <a href="#bottomSection" className="scroll-button">
        <img src="images/arrow_down.svg" alt="scroll to bottom" />
      </a>
      <button class="invisible-button" onClick={onSearchCardClick}>
        <img id="search-image" alt={imgAlt} style={cardStyles} src={card.src} />
      </button>
      <div id="bottomSection"></div>
    </div>
  );
```

[image]

#

I have a down-arrow on the top left just below the x which scrolls to the bottom, first I want it to be at the bottom as in the image below and only appear if `card.src` is longer than the view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can position it to the bottom by making it fixed in CSS and then putting it to the bottom right like this:

```
.scroll-button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: The down-arrow image disappears

Comment: @Ada like this:  `.scroll-button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: 10%;
}` and tinker with it till you get it where you want.

Comment: Hmmm try adding a z-index to it.  so like `z-index 99;` and see if it shows up

Comment: Do you have anymore code you can share? Or put it in a jsfiddle or something?  I am unsure why this isn't working without some context.

Comment: Maybe how SearchCard is rendered. I am not quite sure if it is relevant

Comment: @ada Yes that could possibly help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215415/discussion-between-ada-and-john).

Comment: I got it fixed a few moments ago

Comment: @Ada what was the issue?